# Design and write an algorithm to perform the minimum number of trials

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

Suppose you are asked to design an algorithm for the stress test on samples of a product (say glass jars) to determine the highest pressure that can be exerted (or the height that can be dropped) and still not break. The setup for this experiment on a particular type of jars is as follows:  During a trial a robot manipulator holds a jar and takes it to a height h (an integer) specified by the user and drops it from there, where l<=h,<=n ,  and n is an integer denoting the maximum height.  Provide pseudo-code or clearly defined steps for each of the following algorithms.

a. Design and write an algorithm to perform the minimum number of trials (MNT) to determine the highest safe height (HSH). Determine MNT in terms of n.

b. Design and write an algorithm to break the minimum number of jars needed to find HSH. Determine MNT in terms of n.

Would this be a valid answer? If so why does he use `(3*h)/4`

```
//problem 4 (a)
int h = 1;
boolean itBroke = false;

while (!itBroke) {
    itBroke = dropJar(h);
    h = (3*h)/4;
}

h = h/2; //this algorithm is C(n)=O(log(n))
System.out.Println("The maximum height the jar can be dropped is " + h );
//dropJar is a method that drops the jar from a height of "height" and
//returns a boolean value of whether or not the jar broke.

//problem 4 (b)
boolean itBroke = false;
int h = 1;

for (int i=0; i<h; i++) { //this algorithm is C(n)=O(n)
    itBroke = dropJar(h);
    if(!itBroke)
        h++;
}

h--;
System.out.Println("The maximum height the jar can be dropped is " + h);
```

Comment: No, your answer for 4(a) is not a valid answer, and I didn't bother to read 4(b).  Why don't you think about what the *second* value of `h` is going to be, in the algorithm that you've given for 4(a)?

Comment: What's the quickest known way to find an element in a sorted array?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `x = SortedArray[0];`.  There, I found one.

Comment: This was asked years ago in a google conference I assisted. a) is very easy, and it is not 3h/4, b) is not a linear search, it is a mix between solution of a) and linear search

Comment: well I'm confused. So all of what I have is trash? :/

Comment: @user3698233 sadly it's all wrong, yes.

Comment: @ajb touché. Underspecification, the bane of all software developers.

Comment: @user3698233: A loop going from 0 to 1 by steps of 1 doesn't make much sense. Dividing 3 by 4 using integer division doesn't make much sense either. And the keyword in "binary search" is "binary". Binary doesn't mean 3/4.

Comment: When working on algorithm, you should first write the algorithm in a piece of paper and then test it and measure its results. Only after designing the algorithm at its best, implement it.

Comment: Because 30 seconds of checking would allow the OP to see that the value of `h` in case 4a goes 1, 0, 0, 0 ... and never finds anything.  Asking the entire world whether something is right, when it's so _obviously_ wrong, deserves as many downvotes as we can muster between us.

Comment: Also, I don't believe the OP wrote this code - he/she writes "If so why does he use `(3*h)/4`".  So to say he/she has made two attempts is probably false.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No-one should ever post code and ask other people whether it's right with no self-attempt at analysis. Ever. If you can't find a working solution, post an incorrect one with an analysis showing incorrectness (and possibly failed attempts to make it work) and ask for a working solution - way more useful. Then there'd be no [answers with next-to-no-future-value showing why it doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24002772/1711796). Also, it seems like 2 separate questions, which should be 2 separate questions.

Comment: Clearly this is in a book.. he meaning the author.

Comment: What's the source of this problem?  We require that you [properly credit your sources](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).  The problem seems to be identical to problem 3 in [CS560 Assignment #1](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~tarokh/lab/CS560-Sp11/Assignments/CS560-Assignment1.doc) from SDSU.  Please provide attribution.  See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/63643/755.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 4.a) is obviously incorrect. For instance, if MSH = 2, it will do:

```
dropJar(1);
h = (3*h)/4 = 3 / 4 = 0;
dropJar(0);
h = (3*h)/4 = 0 / 4 = 0;
dropJar(0);
h = (3*h)/4 = 0 / 4 = 0;
...
```

That is, it will never terminate, and need an infinite number of trials. That's obviously not minimal.

A reasonable algorithm would be a binary search, which requires O(log n) trials.

The answer to 4.b) is correct, as it finds the maximum safe height by breaking a single jar. This is clearly optimal, as we can not discover the MSH without breaking a jar. However, the implementation could be simplified to:

```
int h = 0;
do {
    itBroke = dropJar(h);
} while (!itBroke);
return h - 1;
```

Obviously, this requires h = O(n) trials.

Comment: What if I told you that you can do b) using 2 jars and less time.

Comment: Then I'd say that I already know that, but it is not a valid solution to OP's question because the number of jars broken is not minimal.

Comment: a. The absolute minimum number of trials is obtained by dichotomic search: repeatedly try the height in the middle of the possible range (try the height (1+n)/2; if the jar breaks breaks, you know that the HSH is between 1 and (1+n)/2; otherwise, it is between (1+n)/2 and n...).

The MNT will equal Lg(n) (Lg denotes base 2 logarithm), because every trial halves the uncertainty, from n down to 1.

This strategy is optimal because every trial gives you exactly one bit of information (broken/safe), and the solution requires Lg(n) bits of information in total (it is a number between 1 and n).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is not a homework first of all.
the answer is pretty clear, it follows a hint:
you have two states: 0 = jar is not broken, 1= jar is broken

Suppose now, that you know that up to a certain point the jar can hold and after a certain height the jar will brake. Thus you have a sequence of:

```
000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111
```

where the change from 0 to 1 means the jar is broken.
The most easy and well known algorithm finds the first 1 in lokg(k) where k is the position of the first 1.
In this way you both have the optimum(which does not mean minimum) number of trial and the  highest safe height (this time for sure the correct one)

Comment: This only applies for a), not for b).

Comment: you mean the convers, b) is the height and a) is the number of trial, or did I get it wrong?

Comment: No, I mean that this helps you to find a), but not b).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think it helps you in both, once you know at which step the jar brakes then you know such height.. every place in the previous 00..0111..11 means a different height (suppose is incremental), thus you can achive both..